# Integrating Nutch on Hortownworks OR YARN

Tags: hadoop, web-crawler, nutch, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to crawl the web. Preferably with Nutch.
Did not find the references if Hortownworks out of the box supports Nutch.

Has any one integrated Nutch on YARN specially with Hortonworks HDP ?
Or someone has tried integrating Nutch on the Hadoop 2.x (YARN) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HDP 2.3 doesn't support Nutch out of the box (There is a chart on the HDP website showing supported services: [HDP2.3 What's New](http://hortonworks.com/hdp/whats-new/)). However it does support the services that Nutch depends on. A custom Ambari Service could be defined and added to the HDP 2.3 stack definition to enable support for Nutch.